# MongoDB query to return multiple values from an array

Tags: mongodb-query

I think I'm almost there with what I want to do but I'm falling at the last hurdle. I need to extract multiple values from a nested array along with a count.

I have many documents that looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("547db34cd9460c25e6000002"),
    "doc_number" : "500715",
    "error_list" : [ 
        {
            "extractor" : "Code Check",
            "message_number" : "RC9999",
            "message" : "Code is not synchronised"
        }, 
        {
            "extractor" : "Metadata Check",
            "message_number" : "RC1043",
            "message" : "No metadata for document"
        }, 
        {
            "extractor" : "Property Extractor",
            "message_number" : "PE1012",
            "message" : "No properties found"
        }
    ]
}
```

I can query the collection to get a count of each error code with:

```
db.errors.aggregate( 
  [ 
    { $unwind : "$error_list" }, 
    { $group : 
        { _id : "$error_list.message_number", 
            count: { $sum : 1 } 
         }
     }
  ] 
);
```

and return this:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "PE1012",
            "count" : 12
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "RC1043",
            "count" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "RC9999",
            "count" : 10
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

What I would like to add to the results is the message text. I can't quite work out how to do that so any help would be great.

I would like the results to look similar to this:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "PE1012",
            "count" : 12,
            "message" : "No properties found"

        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "RC1043",
            "count" : 2,
            "message" : "No metadata for document"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "RC9999",
            "count" : 10,
            "message" : "Code is not synchronised"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of the [$first](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) or [$last](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) operators, if all the records having the same error code would also have the same error message.

```
db.errors.aggregate( 
  [ 
    { $unwind : "$error_list" }, 
    { $group : { "_id" : "$error_list.message_number",
                 "message":{$first:"$error_list.message"}, 
                 "count": { $sum : 1 }}
     }
  ] 
);
```

If they have could have different error messages then you need to form an array of error messages using [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/).

```
db.errors.aggregate( 
  [ 
    { $unwind : "$error_list" }, 
    { $group : { "_id" : "$error_list.message_number",
                 "messages":{$addToSet:"$error_list.message"}, 
                 "count": { $sum : 1 }}
     }
  ] 
);
```

Comment: Sorry for my slow reply. This is exactly what I was after, Thank you for your excellent explanation.